# how to renumber php fields in tables automatically

Tags: php

this is my code. it's understandable to create numerous tables automatically with building-up

```html
 <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    #
                </th>
                <th>Ball</th>

                <th>Tiesmodel</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            foreach ($dogs as $dog) { ?>
                <tr>

                    <td> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $dog->getBall(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $dog->getTiesmodel(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you question is?

Comment: Don't understand u r question.. what u exactly want

Comment: Confusingly the question is in the title "how to renumber php fields in tables automatically"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a counter just before executing `foreach` and keep them increment it for each iteration. Like this,

```
<?php
            $i=1;
            foreach ($dogs as $dog) { ?>
                <tr>

                    <td><?php echo $i; $i++; ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $dog->getBall(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $dog->getTiesmodel(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

---

You can also use `foreach` to get the `index` automatically like this,

```
<?php
                foreach ($dogs as $index=>$dog) { ?>
                    <tr>

                        <td><?php echo $index; ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $dog->getBall(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dog->getTiesmodel(); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
```

In above method you won't have to increment the `index` manually, `foreach` does that for you.